# Maximum update depth exceeded by adding value to select element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have made a small simple app with the latest version of React and React Router. It was working as expected - Its a styleguide app that lets a user select a component to view and select a brand to be applied to the component.

I am using two select elements. Adding `value={props.component}` leads to the error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

```
<IonSelect
          value={props.component}
          onIonChange={event => props.handleComponentPick(event)}
          interface="popover"
          placeholder="Select One"
        >
          <IonSelectOption value="button">Button</IonSelectOption>
          <IonSelectOption value="card">Card</IonSelectOption>
        </IonSelect>
```

I am not using the change event to directly change state - rather the event changes the URL (using React Router) and the changed route changes the state:

```
                path="/:component/:brand/"
                render={props => (
                  <DisplayComponent
                    {...props}
                    setBrandandComponentState={this.setBrandandComponentState}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

That function just does what its name suggests:

```
  setBrandandComponentState = (brand, component) => {
    this.setState({
      brand: brand,
      component: component
    });
  };
```

I'm not sure what code is relevant to the problem, but the component being displayed by the route is:

```
class DisplayComponent extends Component<any> {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const match = this.props.match;
    this.props.setBrandandComponentState(
      match.params.brand,
      match.params.component
    );
    document.body.setAttribute("brand", match.params.brand);
  };

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (
      this.props.match.params.brand !== prevProps.match.params.brand ||
      this.props.match.params.component !== prevProps.match.params.component
    ) {
      const match = this.props.match;
      this.props.setBrandandComponentState(
        match.params.brand,
        match.params.component
      );
      document.body.setAttribute("brand", match.params.brand);
    }
  };

  render() {
    switch (this.props.match.params.component) {
      case "button":
        return <Button />;
      case "card":
        return <Card />;
      default:
        return <p>No component selected</p>;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your state in componentDidMount which will cause you component to re-render, this is an infinite loop hence the error. If you want to set your state to props on initialize then you should use the contructor (make sure you call super):

```
class DisplayComponent extends Component<any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const match = this.props.match;
    this.props.setBrandandComponentState(
      match.params.brand,
      match.params.component
    );
    document.body.setAttribute("brand", match.params.brand);
  };
```

Comment: I think what you mean here is componentDidUpdate. Calling setState in componentDidMount won't trigger infinite loop.

Comment: Moving the logic into the constructor rather than `componentDidMount` did not fix the problem

Comment: I can understand why the problem is happening. What I can't understand is how I am meant to set state depending on the URL without this problem occurring.

Comment: What do you want to use the state for? I can't see where it's used, the render is just using props.

Comment: I'm rendering a couple of other things elsewhere on the page based on state.

Comment: Does that state change during the life of the component? If you're just updating the url to change the props then you don't need to add it to the state. Components update when props change, you can remove componentDidUpdate

Comment: How can I even handle the URL change if I don't keep track of both values. When the onchange event fires on the select, I update the URL, but only one of the values will come from the event - I need to have access to the other one. In my event handler I have ```handleComponentPick(event: any) {
    const component = event.target.value;
    this.props.history.push(`/${component}/${this.state.brand}`);
  }```

Comment: You shouldn't be keeping track of the values or handling the URL change, that is the job of react-router. The URL change should be detected by the router, it should match your routes with the URL and render the component you want. Are you using it like [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route)? It looks like you are trying to write the code for logic that react-router handles.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I've tried replacing all uses of state with `this.props.match.params.brand` but am getting the error `Property 'brand' does not exist on type '{}'`

Comment: That's pretty similar. I rewrote everything based on your comment. Its a very small project and the code is here: https://github.com/o-t-w/reonic I'm still having problems with this approach though. I now get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`